# Can open self-compiled emacs only in terminal, not with gnome

Tags: emacs, debian, gnome, gnome-3

On debian wheezy with gnome, I've compiled the newest emacs version, following http://valera-rozuvan.github.io/nintoku/installing/emacs/debian/wheezy/installing-emacs-on-debian-wheezy/.

I can open emacs with terminal now, by just executing "emacs", but when I try to open with the gnome user interface, under "activities" or with alt-f2 I get this error:

child process "emacs" could not be executed. (File or directory not found)

How to fix this?

Comment: is emacs in the $path of whatever gnome's using for its launcher? "file not found" suggests it's not.

Comment: Yes it is, just checked again. If it wasn't I couldn't even open it from the terminal by executing "emacs".

Comment: Your terminal may have a different `$PATH` than your Gnome environment.

Comment: Gnome does not normally read `.bashrc`.